# What to do when there's a problem with a tag?

Tags: discussion, tags

Not really a question as such but I don't seem to have the reputation here to do something about this tag that seems to have resulted from a typo.

[propagando](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/propagando)

It showed up when I was searching for propaganda.

There doesn't seem to be a link anywhere to signal it to a mod.

Answer (score 5):

Suggest an edit, retag the question within.

Every day, tags that have no associated questions ("zombie tags") are [automatically deleted](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/71123/i-accidentally-created-a-tag-how-do-i-delete-it) by script.

P.S. Just noticed [propoganda](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/propoganda), will do the same now.

Comment: I don't see an edit feature so maybe I need more reputation points. If zombie tags are automatically cleaned up that's cool :)

Comment: I believe that the edit does not require any reputation because it is the essential core of SE philosophy. The other thing is that your edits sit in "suggested edits" queue unless you have [1,000 rep](http://politics.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/edit) (on this site). A while ago, we [used to have](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/177265/kill-the-retag-option-use-just-edit) a separate retag privilege which is gone for now.

Comment: can you describe where an edit link can be found? I'm on `http://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/propagando`. The edit I can see if for adding favourites.

Comment: No, you're supposed to edit the individual questions and there change the list of tags. On the tag page, you may edit excerpt and description, not the tag name.

Comment: Ok I can change the list of tags but I can't seem to do much on the page itself. Thanks :)